# Can't Get DIVs To .fadeOut() When Another DIV Is Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make something where the user double clicks on an icon, and then a DIV with the same id value as the icons' class value fades out. I have something that kind of works but for some reason it only works for the very first DIV. Here's my current code:

```
$('#icon').on('dblclick', function() {
    var app = $(this).attr('class');
    $('#' + app + '').fadeOut(200);
});
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/TheInfection/JpMRC/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are using one ID for the several elements, IDs must be unique, only the first element with a specific ID is selected by jQuery, you should use `class`es or `data-*` attributes instead.

```
<div data-target="one" class="icon">one</div>
<div data-target="two" class="icon">two</div>
<div data-target="three" class="icon">three</div>

<div id="one" class="box">One</div>
<div id="two" class="box">Two</div>
<div id="three" class="box">Three</div>
```

```
$('.icon').on('dblclick', function() {
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $('#' + target).fadeOut(200);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VqWJp/

Comment: And a little addition: In the code he provided, he assigns the `class` attribute to the variable `app` which is then used as an ID selector (`'#' + app`). This simply cannot work. ;)

Comment: Thank you so much! This was bothering me for days.

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div class="icon one"></div>
<div class="icon two"></div>
<div class="icon three"></div>

<div id="one" class="box">One</div>
<div id="two" class="box">Two</div>
<div id="three" class="box">Three</div>
```

js:

```
$('.icon').on('dblclick', function() {
    var app = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
    $('#' + app).fadeOut(200);
});
```

upd: previous decision is better, I think.